# ObservableCollection is not updated when item are added to database directly

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, observablecollection

I'm using EF to connect to my database. I have a `DbContext` that I use to get a `DbSet<MyDataModel>`. I use an `ObservableCollection<MyDataModel>` to bind the data to a `GridView` in WPF. This is how I populate the collection:

```
ObservableCollection<MyDataModel> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyDataModel>(dataContect.MyDataModels);
```

The problem is that my database is updated from another source (another application completely) and the `ObservableCollection` does not detect when an item is added to the database. I don't see how it would, but I don't know how I can make it? The database contains a lot of entries (>10k) so I would prefer not reloading all the entries periodically..

What can I do?

**Edit:**
I think I was a bit unclear (and not really sure of how `ObservableCollections` works), but yeah, I realize now that my main question is how to refresh the `DbContext` when the database is updated. It doesn't really have much to do with the `ObservableCollection` itself.

Comment: Do you have any control over the other application?

Comment: Actually I do, but it's basically just a service pumping data into the database and it's completely decoupled from the UI

Comment: In that case see my answer. Your updating service could publish a message that is subscribed to by your application. Upon receipt of the message your application could then either refresh it's data source, or it could receive the actual change set itself.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but due to a couple of circumstances I can't really use that solution. I've been looking at SqlDependency before, maybe I should give it another look

Comment: That's fair enough - these things are rarely straight forward! The key thing with `SqlDependency` is that you really need to minimise the number of listeners, so if your app is used by lots of users you should monitor through a central service that can notify clients.

Comment: Ok, the number of clients will be very modest, so I don't think it will be a problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the fundamental issue is that you need to know that something has changed that your application needs to know about.

If you have any control over the second application then you could publish a message from that to let your application know it needs to reload (or maybe even it could publish the changes themselves).

If you have no control over the other application you need to detect these yourself. You could use something like [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx), although this is not appropriate for client applications. You would need a central service to perform the monitoring and then publish a change notification.

I could of course be completely wrong and there may be something built into EF to notify of changes.

Answer (score 2):

An Observable Collection notifies your UI when items are added. 
If you bind to it your interface will update properly.

You still have to add items to your Observable collection for this behaviour to be triggered.
So you will still have to Refresh your DataContext.

Check out [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233770/AutoRefresh-Entity-Framework-data-using-SQL-Server) to force a refresh from SQL server

Answer (score 1):

As implied by the name, the observable collection is observable, but it does not observe anithing. It's pourpose is to notify when someone add/remoce item from that, so you can use it to have an UI reflecting automatically the changes in the collection.